# How to solve zsh: permission denied: mkdocs after pip installation?

Tags: python, pip, mkdocs

I installed mkdocs using pip3. At the beginning, I couldn't run mkdocs => I got mkdocs command not found. Then, I located the installation path of pip and modified my ~/.zshrc path

```
bash pip3 show mkdocs  

Name: mkdocs
Version: 1.3.0
Summary: Project documentation with Markdown.
Home-page: https://www.mkdocs.org
Author: Tom Christie
Author-email: tom@tomchristie.com
License: BSD
Location: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages
Requires: click, ghp-import, importlib-metadata, Jinja2, Markdown, mergedeep, packaging, PyYAML, pyyaml-env-tag, watchdog
Required-by:
```

The problem is that now if I run mkdocs I get in return:

`zsh: permission denied: mkdocs`

That is, I guess, because the Library directory in which pip installs is outside of the my user directory and I don't have write access to it.

What's the smartest move to solve it?

Comment: Try this `pip show mkdocs` what will you get?

Comment: You see it in my post.

Comment: Did you follow this? [Getting Started with MkDocs](https://www.mkdocs.org/getting-started/#theming-our-documentation)

Comment: @EnricoBottazzi I have run into the same error. Did you resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

I had same error (Windows 10). Worked when starting mkdocs with `python -m mkdocs build`

Answer (score 0):

For similar issue in mac I used  `python3 -m mkdocs --version`